# Comprehension of the definition of 2nd partial derivatives on Riemannian manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given a Riemannian manifold with a Riemannian connection, let $e_i$ be a moving frame, $\omega^i$ be its dual frame, $\omega_i^j$ be its connection 1-form. Here is a way to define 1-st and 2-nd partial derivative:
$$ \begin{cases} f_i\omega^i:=\mathrm{d}f\\
f_{ij}\omega^j:=\mathrm{d}f_i-f_j\omega_i^j\end{cases}$$

My question is:

1. Why do we define the 2-nd derivative in this way? Are there any intuition inside? (I think probably one intuition is that we can differentiate the both side, apply $\mathrm{\omega_i}=\omega_j^i\wedge \omega_j$ to get:
   $$ (\mathrm{d}f_i-f_j\omega_j^i)\wedge \omega^i=0$$
   But I cannot see any further.)

Edit: From here we deduce that the definition in this way can ensure $f_{ij}=f_{ji}$. But I wonder if there is a more natural reason to define in this way.

2. For example, if we just define $f_{ij}\omega^j:=\mathrm{d}f_i$, what is the problem? Does this definition leads to any contradiction?

Any hints or comments are welcomed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

For the second question. If we apply $e_i$ to the first equation we obtain, for any smooth function $\varphi$
$$
 \varphi \circ f_i= e_i (\varphi \circ f)
$$
If now $f_{ij} \omega^j= df_i$ we have
$$
\varphi \circ f_{ij}= e_j e_i(\varphi \circ f)
$$
Notice that $f_{ij}=f_{ji}$ implies that $[e_i,e_j]=0$. In general moving frames doesn't need to be formed by commuting vector fields, so this is false.

I think the whole reason to define partial derivatives in that way is to assure that there is symmetry between the second partial derivatives. It looks pretty "natural" as a condition to impose to me, but I'm only guessing.

Comment: Thanks! I think your guess make sense.